# Gradle scala class already defined with combined Java compilation

Tags: java, scala, gradle

I have the following scala compilation issue

- scala -> depends upon java source
- java source -> depends upon scala source
- My scala code is in src/main/scala
- My java code is in src/main/java

I cant change this code so I need to compile this with gradle and it currently compiles with JRuby just fine.

I have read the following posts on how to solve this issue:

http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_to_compile_a_java_class_that_depends_on_a_scala_class_in_gradle

http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_to_compile_a_java_class_that_depends_on_a_scala_class_in_gradle

I added this to my build:

```
ext {
    baseName = 'd2'
    description = 'Divisional IVR.'
    combinedSources = "$buildDir/combined-sources"
}

apply plugin: 'scala'

compileScala.taskDependencies.values = compileScala.taskDependencies.values - 'compileJava'
compileJava.dependsOn compileScala

sourceSets.main.scala.srcDir "$combinedSources"
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = []
```

I tried to copy all the scala and java files to one location:

```
compileScala.dependsOn{
    copyAllSourceFiles
}

task copyAllSourceFiles(type:Copy) {
    description = 'Copy All Source Files.'
    from('src/main/java') {}
    from('/src/main/scala') {}
    into combinedSources

    includeEmptyDirs = false
}
```

But now I get an error:

```
[ant:scalac] Compiling 18 source files to C:\usr\git_workspaces\xivr\d2\target\classes\main
[ant:scalac] Compiling 18 scala and 196 java source files to C:\usr\git_workspaces\xivr\d2\target\classes\main
[ant:scalac] C:\usr\git_workspaces\xivr\d2\target\combined-sources\com\comcast\ivr\d2\actors\AlternateAniWithAccountActor.scala:9: error: AlternateAniWithAccountActor is already defined as class AlternateAniWithAccountActor
```

It almsot seems like scalaCompile sees $combinedSources and 'src/main/scala'

Answer (score 2):

> It almsot seems like scalaCompile sees $combinedSources and 'src/main/scala'

That's how you configured it: `src/main/scala` is the default, and you added `"$combinedSources"`. To override the default, use `sourceSets.main.scala.srcDirs = [combinedSources]`.

In any case, you don't have to (and shouldn't) copy sources around. Here is one solution that neither requires copying nor reconfiguring of task dependencies:

```
sourceSets.main.scala.srcDir "src/main/java"
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = []
```

Now, your Java and Scala code will get joint-compiled, and can depend on each other arbitrarily.

PS: Instead of `"$combinedSources"`, use `combinedSources`.

Answer (score 1):

#### gradle.properties

```
theVersion=2.1
theSourceCompatibility=1.7
theScalaVersion=2.10.3
```

#### build.gradle

```
apply {
    plugin 'scala'
    plugin 'java'
    plugin 'idea'
}

ext {
    scalaVersion = theScalaVersion
}

sourceCompatibility = theSourceCompatibility

tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    scalaCompileOptions.useAnt = false
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:$theScalaVersion"
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:$theScalaVersion"
}

sourceSets {
    main.scala.srcDirs = ["src/main/scala", "src/main/java"]
    main.java.srcDirs = []
}
```